# How to get Delta from two Mysql Tables by Date

Tags: mysql

i have two mysql tables with the same structure. now i want to get all records in table1 thats newer than the same record in table2.

```
table 1

id    name   namespace   updated
437   test   test/test1  2016-09-02 09:17:13
436   test   test/test2  2016-09-04 09:17:13
435   test   test/test3  2016-09-05 09:17:13

table 2
id    name   namespace   updated
433   test   test/test1  2016-09-02 09:17:13
434   test   test/test2  2016-09-04 09:17:13
437   test   test/test3  2016-09-04 09:17:13
```

the result is always more than expected

here is my statement

```
SELECT a.`id` , a.`name` , a.`namespace`, a.`created` , 
a.`updated` 
FROM table1 AS a
LEFT JOIN table2 AS b ON a.`name` = b.`name` 
AND a.`namespace` = b.`namespace` 
WHERE a.`updated` > b.`updated`
```

whats wrong?

thank you.

Comment: What should be the output?

Comment: BTW your `where` clause turns your `left join` into an `inner join`

Comment: Are `name` and `namespace` the same for every `id`?

Comment: it should return only the record with the id 435 because this ist newer than the equivalent in table2 (437)

Comment: name and namespace are not the same for every id.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a left join don set value related  in left joined  table in where clause otherwise these work as an inner join

add  AND to your ON clause

and last check for null left join value for not joined  rows

```
  SELECT a.`id` , a.`name` , a.`namespace`, a.`created` , 
  a.`updated` 
  FROM table1 AS a
  LEFT JOIN table2 AS b ON a.`name` = b.`name` 
  AND a.`namespace` = b.`namespace` and  a.`updated` > b.`updated` 
  where b.id is null
```

and

Try avoid millisecond

```
SELECT a.`id` , a.`name` , a.`namespace`, a.`created` , 
  a.`updated` 
  FROM table1 AS a
  LEFT JOIN table2 AS b ON a.`name` = b.`name` 
  AND a.`namespace` = b.`namespace` 
   and DATE_FORMAT(a.`updated`,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') > DATE_FORMAT(b.`updated`,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')
  where b.id is null
```

Comment: thanks for that. but this returns also records where 'updated' is the same in both tables.  I only want the newer

Comment: which data type is the column updated??  you have time in miilliseconds?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I came up with a solution where it always returns you the most recent id for each `namespace`.

For that I created an [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d2eee4/25) and came up with the following code:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT * FROM table1 
     UNION
     SELECT * FROM table2
     ORDER BY updated DESC
    ) A
GROUP BY A.namespace
ORDER BY updated DESC
```

> This does not catch that one id could be the latest for 2 namespaces

Comment: thanks for the try and the SQLfiddle. but this returns me 3 records. with the sql i mentioned before i get the right result of one, thats weird.  but when i run the sql with real data it returns records with the same date (updated).
i just want all records in table1 that have a newer date in col 'updated' 

btw. the id's doesn't match.

Comment: @stacker ah okay, I didnt understand what exactly you want to achieve. I guess then my approach wont work, but I’m gonna look into it later again.